# Why is my jquery .change event only running once on radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3F6TY/

You'll need Bootstrap.js for this.

Some other SA threads said that this could be a delegation issue, but I see no reason to delegate in the code that I have since the selector never changes or disappears in the HTML.

When I click on `First Radio` the accordion goes down, but when I click off it the accordion doesn't hide like I want it to. I have my code written so that on `change` of the radio button, it checks to see if the radio button is checked, and if not, it collapses the accordion.

```
          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="firstRadio" value="">
              First Radio
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 panel-collapse collapse" id="firstAccordion">
            <div>
              First Accordion
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="secondRadio">
              Second Radio
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 panel-collapse collapse" id="secondAccordion">
            <div>
              Second Accordion
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="thirdRadio">
              Third Radio with no Accordion
            </label>
          </div>


$('input[id="firstRadio"]').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('show');

    } else {

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('hide');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event is attached only to the first radio button. The change event is triggered *only* on the radio button the user has clicked, so clicking on any other radio button the event on the first one isn't triggered.

In other words, the event is not triggered only once but it looks that way because it's triggered only when clicking on the first radio button.

Attach the event to all the radio buttons instead:

```
$('input[name="radios"]').change( function() {
    if ($('#firstRadio').is(":checked")){
        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('show');
    } else {
        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3F6TY/1/)

Comment: Hmmm? I don't get it. When a user clicks another radio button, the first radio button automatically gets unchecked, meaning it gets `changed`, right?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't trigger the change event.

Comment: Oh geez. I can't find anywhere in the documentation that says that. How are you supposed to know that unticking the radio button doesn't actually trigger the change event? Also, is there some other event listener that *would* work when a radio button gets unchecked by way of something else getting checked? IMO what just happened shows a clear deficiency in the .change listener.

Comment: The reason it works that way is that the usual use case is checking if the radio group has changed at all, and you don't want that event to happen twice. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ED49/ If it triggered once for the button that gets unchecked and again for the one that gets checked you'd have the event triggering twice on each click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out.. I did this for you but try to code by yourself next time.. That will help you a lot..

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "firstRadio"){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('#firstAccordion').show("fast");
                $('#secondAccordion').hide("fast");
                $('#thirdAccordion').hide("fast");
            }
        } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "secondRadio"){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('#firstAccordion').hide("fast");
                $('#secondAccordion').show("fast");
                $('#thirdAccordion').hide("fast");
            }
        } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "thirdRadio"){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('#firstAccordion').hide("fast");
                $('#secondAccordion').hide("fast");
                $('#thirdAccordion').show("fast");
            }
        }
  });
```